# Easy iOS Line of Code Explanation

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am doing the 'Your Second App' tutorial and it has me add the line of code below that is a setter for the masterBirdSightingList property. I just have a basic questions on it:

Is this line the same as if I were to synthesize it? If not, what makes it different?

```
- (void)setMasterBirdSightingList:(NSMutableArray *)newList
{
     if (_masterBirdSightingList != newList) {
            _masterBirdSightingList = [newList mutableCopy];
     }
}
```

Comment: This depends on the property declaration for masterBirdSightingList. It is strong, weak or copy, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the property is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *masterBirdSightingList;
```

then implementing this method is not the same as simply using `@synthensize masterBirdSightingList;`.

Defining a property with `copy` semantics for a mutable container type doesn't actually work as expected using the default synthesized setter.

Without the explicit method, you actually end up with the property referencing an immutable copy of the array.

By using the code you posted, instead of relying on the synthesized method, you get the proper and expected behavior of having a mutable copy of the original array.

Another way to look at this is that calling `copy` on an `NSMutableArray` returns an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`. This is why the default synthesized property setter doesn't work as expected (when dealing with a mutable container property). So you must implement the setter yourself and call `mutableCopy` on the parameter.

Comment: quick follow up question - so why would anyone want to use 'copy' in the property definition if you just have to use a custom synthesizer? Seems like it is more work for nothing.

Comment: If the property is defined with `copy` and the type is an immutable one, then things work as expected without the need to explicitly write the setter method. You want to use `copy` for a property whenever you want to ensure the property's value doesn't get changed behind your back. Without `copy`, if the original value is changed, then the value of your property is also changed. There are times where this is OK, but most times this isn't desired.